# Regex - match whole word in parsley.js

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsley.js

How do I match two entire words with `or(|)` operand in parsley.js' `data-parsley-pattern` attribute?

As you can see I want to match the words `user` and `moderator`.

I have tried: `data-parsley-pattern="/(user|moderator)/"` which is normal regex and works with other standardised regular expression matching like regex101.com:
https://regex101.com/r/kD7sR1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern should work, as long as you are using a full form with `/.../`, otherwise the pattern would be anchored. You don't even need the parenthesis but they won't hurt either.

Here's a [working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vebwjp?editors=101) that simply uses

```
<input data-parsley-pattern="/user|moderator/" type="text" name="fullname" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [`data-parsley-pattern` **2.0** documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-validators-list):

> Validates that a value matches a specific regular expression (regex). 
>   Note that patterns are anchored, i.e. must match the whole string. 
>   Parsley deviates from the standard for patterns looking like `/pattern/{flag}`; these are interpreted as litteral regexp and are not anchored.

So, it looks like your regex should work.

If it does not, try

```
data-parsley-pattern="/[\s\S]*(user|moderator)[\s\S]*/"
```

The `[\s\S]*` will match zero or more characters (any, including newlines).

Comment: Acc. to the [reference page](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-validators-list), a single ``\`` should work.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Patterns are anchored, unless they look like `/pattern/` with an optional flag afterwards, in which case they are not.

Comment: True: *Parsley deviates from the standard for patterns looking like /pattern/{flag}; these are interpreted as litteral regexp and are not anchored.* So, what is the point of asking the question? Maybe the version used still requires anchoring?

Comment: Indeed, I think the OP is somehow mistaken. Older versions didn't anchor the patterns so I don't think it has always worked.

Comment: Anyway, great you noticed that.